# How to make code execute at each week end?

Tags: node.js, intervals

I want to execute a piece code each Sunday 23:59 (11 pm) (basically at the end of each week). However, it should only be fired once per week.

A `setInterval()` function won't cut it here, as the app might be restarted meanwhile.

If this will help anyhow, I had this basic idea:

> Set an interval (with `setInterval`) for every 5-10 seconds and check if it's Sunday and hour 23 (11 pm). However, this solution will be inconsistent and may fire more than once a week. I need a more bullet-proof solution to this.

Comment: Maybe a Cron Job would be the way to go.... https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any cron module (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and set job for `59 23 * * 0` ([ranges](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron#cron-ranges))

```
const { CronJob } = require('cron');
const job = new CronJob('59 23 * * 0', mySundayFunc);
job.start();
```

Comment: Ok, I will try your solution out. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

How about calculating the remaining time on start, like this code

```js
const WEEK_IN_MS = 604800000;
const ONE_HOUR_IN_MS = 3600000;
const FOUR_DAYS_IN_MS = 4 * WEEK_IN_MS / 7;

function nextInterval() {
    return WEEK_IN_MS - ((Date.now() + FOUR_DAYS_IN_MS) % WEEK_IN_MS) - ONE_HOUR_IN_MS;
}

const interval =  nextInterval();

console.log(`run after ${interval} ms`);

setTimeout(
    () => console.log('Do it!!!'),
    interval
)
```